# Accessing a created instance of a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, segue

I have a MainViewController and by using prepareforsegue I pass data to my NowPlayingViewController. When I select audio in the MainView everything I need to be pushed is pushing successfully to the NowPlayingViewController, but after going back from the NowPLayingViewController to the MainViewController I have no way of accessing the NowPlayingViewController without selecting a new audio file. From what I understand, when using storyboarding and segues, it automatically creates a new instance of the view. So my question is, how would I have a button on my MainViewController that could access the last instance of NowPlayingViewController?

Answer (score 0):

try overriding `- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent` in your NowPlayingViewController.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please. This is my first time seeing this option. Thanks

Comment: so.. a disclaimer: i've never tried this myself :) but in your NowPlayingViewController you want to have something like: `- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent { MainViewController *mvc = (MainViewController *)parent; mvc.someVar = self.someVar; etc...}`. re-reading your question, this isn't quite what you want - but it would (in theory) allow you to set variables in your `MainViewController` before `NowPlayingViewController` disappears.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to mess around with it and see how it works, but it seems it would. :) thanks. I can't vote up answers as of now, but I will be glad to when I stack overflow allows me too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not use to story board and segue so I might be off the track.
Have you try keeping a pointer to your NowPlayingViewController in your MainViewController? Or a pointer to your player? You could store it before pushing your NowPlayingViewController on the UIViewController presentation stack so you would always have the more recent one.